# The Representation of a number by a (fixed given) binary quadratic form

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Given a binary quadratic form $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2$, find a neccessary and sufficient condition for an arbitrary integer $T$ to be representable by $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2$; i.e. the diophantine equation 
$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2=T$, have solution $x$ and $y$ in integers?

Fermat knew the answer when two squares are added together. Euler discovered many relationships and Gauss proved results for many coefficients.  The question asks for a simple algorithm {using elementary mathematics} to determine $T$ (up to modulus); given $A$, $B$, $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Necessary conditions are related with values of Legendre symbols, but sufficient conditions becomes more and more convoluted as $\left|B^2-4AC\right|$ becomes large. This problem is heavily related with the [class number problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_number_problem). An algorithmic approach due to Kaltofen and Yui is outlined in the last pages of

> D.H. Cox - Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$

which is a book I strongly suggest you to read. To explain or just sketch here all the details of the quadratic forms machinery would be really time consuming, I just mention that the first chapters are dedicated to proving the classical results of Legendre, Lagrange, Euler, Fermat, Gauss et alia on quadratic forms with small discriminants, before moving to the general case.

[These notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/primesoftheform.html) by P.L. Clarke might be helpful, too.

Comment: thanks , I was wondering if there is an "elementary approach' - one that just uses elementary algebra. I have been trying to develop such an approach but I am not sure whether it is the right way to go? Are the steps right..  Where is it?  I am going to write it down below presently.

Comment: @user157310: if the class number is one, the necessary conditions given by Legendre symbols are also sufficient. For instance, every prime $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ is represented by the quadratic form $a^2+b^2$. But if $-5$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod{p}$, that is not enough to be sure $p$ is represented by $a^2+5b^2$.

Comment: So the answer being elementary or not strongly depends on the value of $B^2-4AC$.

Comment: yes I have posted my approach. I was wondering what you think of the approach below. In this example T is the integer to be written in terms of A, B, C.

Comment: I am going to read the book by D.H. Cox. to compare methods.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to post my approach but I do not know whether it is correct.
Here we go:

Proposition:

Let $ A=(PM-pm);  B=[(PN+QM)-(pn+qm)]; C=(QN-qn).$

Then $ T=\frac{(M+N-m-n)c_1+(P+Q-p+q)}{m+n}$ ;  $m+n=+1  $;  $Pq-pQ=1;  ..c_1 $..is a free variable

Proof:

$Write$ $ Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2 - T= GH-JK=0 ...........    (1)$   where

$   G=(Px+Qy+c_1)..................(2)$

$   H=(Mx+Ny+c_2).................(3)$

$   J=(px+qy+c_3)....................(4)  $

$   K=(mx+ny+c_4)...................(5) $

Now we expand the expression $GH-JK=0$ first; but it is also equal to $ Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2-T=0 $

$(Px+Qy+c_1)(Mx+Ny+c_2)-(px+qy+c_3)(mx+ny+c_4)=0.......(6) $

So we expand the above expression in terms of powers  x and y and equate coefficients.

$ (PM-pm)x^2=Ax^2..........(7) ....A=(PM-pm) $

$ [(PN+QM)-(pn+qm)]xy=Bxy..(8) ....B= [(PN+QM)-(pn+qm)]$

$ (QN-qn)y^2=Cy^2..........(9).....C= (QN-qn)$

$[(Qc_2+Nc_1)-(qc_4+nc_3)]y=Dy=0y....(10)$

$[(Pc_2+Mc_1)-(pc_4+mc_3)]x=Ex=0x.....(11)$

$c_1c_2-c_3c_4=-T......(12)$

We add (10) and (11) together noting that the sum is zero;

$[([P+Q]c_2+[M+N]c_1)+([p+q]c_4+[m+n]c_3)]=0x+0y=0........(13)$

$[{(P+Q)-(p+q)}-{(M+N)c_1+(m+n)c_3}]=0..........(14)$

$ ... Put.. c_2=c_4=1;c_1-c_3=-T.............(14a)$  Replace in (14)

$[{(P+Q)-(p+q)}-{(M+N)c_1-(m+n)(c_1+T)}]=0..........(15)$

$[{(P+Q)-(p+q)}-{(M+N)c_1-(m+n)c_1}]=(m+n)T..........(16)$

This is the equation we obtain in the proposition.

Then $ T=\frac{(M+N-m-n)c_1+(P+Q-p+q)}{m+n}$ ;  $m+n=+1  $;  $Pq-pQ=1;  ..c_1 $..is a free variable

The coefficients of x and y are zero; so we use this fact to get T in terms of c1.
We make the choice that c2=c4=1 and c1-c3=-T. Note that (m+n)=1 or -1, ensuring that T is an integer.

Pq-pQ=1 or -1,  which ensures that x and y are integer solutions. This condition can be obtained by solving the 2 linear equations G=0 and J=0 simultaneously and demanding integer solutions for x and y.

Some steps have been omitted but they can be supplied when needed.  What do you think of this method?

Comment: Some simple steps have been omitted. They can be filled in easily.

Comment: Let the coefficients of x and y be D and E in  expansion (6) , then D=0, E=0 and their sum  D+E=0 obviously. This with the other condition c1-c3=-T has been used to find T in terms of m and n, P, Q....

Comment: This problem might have been stated differently.  Given any  integer T {1,2,3...} , the question is , how can we write it  in binary quadratic form Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2 = T?  i.e. Find A, B, C, x,y for any number T.